# Visualising hidden characters

Tags: emacs

I have this function to visualise hidden '︁' (0xfe01) characters.  Could
this be made more general so that all hidden characters in a string get
visualised ?

```
 (defun my-display-hidden (&optional remove)
  "Show/hide the hidden '︁' (0xfe01) characters."
  (interactive "P")
  (if remove (remove-overlays)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward "︁" nil t) ; (0xfe01)
        (let ((ov (make-overlay (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))))
          (overlay-put ov 'display
                       (buttonize "(0xfe01)"
                                  (let ((pos (match-beginning 0)))
                                    (lambda (_) (describe-char pos)))))
          (overlay-put ov 'face 'font-lock-warning-face))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function can be extended to display non-ascii, zero-width characters in a similar manner with the following.

```
(defun my-show-nonascii (&optional remove all)
  "Toggle display of zero-width non-ascii characters in current buffer.
With prefix \\[universal-argument] REMOVE, remove displays.
With prefix \\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument] ALL show all non-ascii chars."
  (interactive (list (eq 4 (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))
                     (eq 16 (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))))
  (if remove (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'nonascii t)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "[[:nonascii:]]" nil t)
        (when (or all (zerop (char-width (char-after (match-beginning 0)))))
          (let ((ov (make-overlay (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))))
            (overlay-put ov 'display
                         (buttonize (format "(%d)" (char-after (match-beginning 0)))
                                    (let ((pos (match-beginning 0)))
                                      (lambda (_) (describe-char pos)))))
            (overlay-put ov 'face 'font-lock-warning-face)
            (overlay-put ov 'nonascii t)))))))
```

Comment: Why the specificity on zero-width characters ? Would it be beneficial for the function to display nonascii characters irrespective of width ?

Comment: yea, I updated it to allow that.  But including non zero-width overlays unicode chars.